# How Can I Evaluate This Kind of Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

How Can I Evaluate this kind of integral?
 $$\int_{e^e}^{+∞} lnx dx$$
Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: You can simply see that it doesn't converge. The point $e^e$ is ok.You can try to write $x=e^t$ then you can see it better. $lnx$ becomes $t$ and you can use the criteria $\frac{1}{x^\lambda}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral itself can be evaluated as follows:

$\int lnxdx=$[integration by parts]$=xlnx-\int xdlnx=xlnx-\int x\frac{1}{x}dx=xlnx-\int dx=x(lnx-1)$

However it does not have a finite limit at infinity. The integral is divergent.